# Unable to start The Samaritan Agenda in The Fractured But Whole on Switch

Tags: south-park-the-fractured-but-whole

I have played The Fractured But Whole until the The Chaos Gambit quest, which I assume I have finished.  I'm at the Freedom Pals, Timmy said he had a mission for me but he disappeared behind a curtain that I'm not allowed to go to.

- Mysterion says I should prove I want to be there

  - Bought all clothes and took pictures of myself there
- Tupperware says he's distracted because his dad got arrested

  - Went to the police station but couldn't get in because of "politics"
- Toolshed simply says that he appreciates me helping him with his dad

There doesn't seem to be anything else to do there.  There are some items to be found and there is a simulator, but I don't feel like those would advance me any further.

[I looked up a guide](https://www.primagames.com/games/south-park-fractured-whole/walkthrough/south-park-fractured-but-whole-missions) and found that I didn't start the mission The Invitation yet.  However, when I go to Steed in SoDoSoPa, there is nobody there.

I don't really know what to do from here.  Is there something I forgot to do?

Comment: You should have received a phone call from "The Kingpin". Then you go to  SoDoSoPa ruins (next to Kenny's house) and start The Invitation. The Samaritan Agenda will not start until you have completed The Invitation.

Comment: I also read in the guide that I should've gotten a phone call, but I never got it. Maybe I've hit a bug in the game?

Comment: Not sure if you hit a bug or not, I can't find an existing bug list that notes something with this quest line. Are you sure you just don't remember? Have you tried going to SoDaSoPa and trying to see if the quest starts?

Comment: When I go to SoDoSoPa the quest does not start, there are some bags with Member Berries on top, when I get close to them the camera zooms on me. There's a cross bow which I remember firing at the start of the game, which back then caused the sound of a cat screaming. It doesn't do anything now. If I'd done the quest but forgot, The Pingpin should've called me I thing? "The Invitation" is not in my completed quests list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like I've encountered a bug in the game.  I started from scratch, this time, I did get the Ninja fight. Furthermore,

> As soon as I entered the Freedom Pals base, Tweek asked me to meet me at his school to have counceling with Craig and Mr. Mackey.

This did not happen on the previous run, despite me getting them to agree on it in both runs.